# In jquery what is the signifigant difference in usng .submit and .click to handle a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I understand how

> $(".button").click(function() {

and

> $('#form').submit(function(e) {

work differently.

One happens when when something is clicked, and the other happens when the form is submitted.

But what is the significant difference in the two? I mean why would you want to handle a form when the submit button is clicked, and why would you want to handle a form when the form is submitted?

What I am asking is, when submitting a form with the post method. What would be the advantage of using one of these methods over the other? Why would you want to use one over the other?

What times would you use .click or .submit?

What are the advantages / disadvantages to the two? Which one if more commonly used?

Please don't split hairs, take my question for what it is worth. I explained it the best O could. Please don't say *well technically it doesn't work like that at all*..

Comment: similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785241/difference-between-handling-form-submit-or-an-input-type-submit-click-e

Comment: Have you ever submitted a form simply by pressing *enter*?

Comment: Of course, but there is sometimes a problem with that. You have to set it up to account for things. Is that the point you're making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a form tells the browser to make a request to the url in the action attribute using the method in the method attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="http://somewebsite/somescript.php">
```

However, the only accepted methods in a form are GET or POST, so you wouldn't want to submit a form if you wanted to make an ajax PUT or DELETE request. You'd instead listen for a click event and make a PUT or DELETE request with javascript (probably jquery) when the button is clicked.

The form submitting has been around since before ajax. While it still works perfectly well, the listening for click events and firing your own ajax calls is quickly becoming more popular as you have more freedom in the type of request you make.

Comment: But if you're flat out submitting a form and using post what would be the difference in using .click and.submit? I mean why would you use one over the other?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use .submit when actually processing a form with post, and click for actions to be handled when clicking the button?

Comment: If you are simply submitting a form using post, the only difference would be that jQuerys submit function would pull the data from the named inputs in the form and post those for you. If you used a $.post request inside of a click event, you would have to grab the data that you want to send from the form manually in the click event and pass it to the $.post method. You'd grab the data with something like $(#inputID).val()

Answer (score 0):

Originally, the click event was added to do something OTHER than post a form. The Submit event was used for that as it passed all the form variables to the page specified in the action part of the tag. click and .submit events reflect directly the core HTML functionality that been around since at least HTML 3.2 to the best of my awareness.(When I first learned HTML.)