# Submit an ajax form just only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, forms

I have this form, and when the user send it, sometimes it gets submitted 2-3-4x, or more, not just only once.

I give the button a disabled, but that didnt solve the problem.

Whats going on wrong? I dont have any idea, what to do with this. If the disabled button wont solve it, what will?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="AjanlatForm" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Az Ön neve:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="AjanlatNev" name="AjanlatNev" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >E-mail címe:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="AjanlatEmail" name="AjanlatEmail" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Telefonszáma:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="AjanlatTel" name="AjanlatTel" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Szállítási cím:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="AjanlatCim" name="AjanlatCim" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Mennyiség:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AjanlatMennyiseg" name="AjanlatMennyiseg">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="btn selectBtn" id="AjanlatMennyisegTipus" name="AjanlatMennyisegTipus">
          <option  value="Darab">Darab</option>
          <option  value="Kamion">Kamion</option>
          <option  value="Raklap">Raklap</option>
          <option  value="Tekercs">Tekercs</option>
          <option  value="Zsák">Zsák</option>
          <option  value="cm">cm</option>
          <option  value="m">m</option>
          <option  value="m2">m2</option>
          <option  value="m3">m3</option>
        </select>
        </span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Üzenet:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <textarea name="AjanlatUzenet" id="AjanlatUzenet" rows="7" class="form-control input-md"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="ajanlat_modal_text">A küldés gombot kérjük csak egyszer nyomja meg.</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="AjanlatTermekID" name="AjanlatTermekID" value="91">
    <button type="button" id="kerdesButton" class="btn btn-default sidebar_button">Ajánlatkérés elküldése</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div id="AjanlatResult"></div>
  </div>
</form>



$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    $("#AjanlatKeresBtn").click(function() 

    {

        $('#AjanlatResult').hide();

        $("#AjanlatModal").modal("show");
        $('#kerdesButton').click(function(e)
        {
            $('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', true);
            e.preventDefault();
            var FormErros = [];
            var AjanlatNev = $('#AjanlatNev').val();
            var AjanlatEmail = $('#AjanlatEmail').val();
            var AjanlatTel = $('#AjanlatTel').val();
            var AjanlatCim = $('#AjanlatCim').val();
            var AjanlatMennyiseg = $('#AjanlatMennyiseg').val();
            var AjanlatUzenet = $('#AjanlatUzenet').val();
            var AjanlatTermekID = $('#AjanlatTermekID').val();
            if($.trim(AjanlatNev) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a nevét."); }
            if($.trim(AjanlatEmail) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg az e-mail címét."); }
            if(AjanlatEmail != "")
            {
                if(validate_Email(AjanlatEmail) == false){FormErros.push("Elképzelhető, hogy hibásan adta meg az e-mail címét.");}
            }
            if($.trim(AjanlatTel) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a telefonszámát."); }
            if($.trim(AjanlatUzenet) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem írt semmilyen kérdést vagy üzenetet."); }
            if($.trim(AjanlatTermekID) == "") { FormErros.push("Hiányzik a termék ID."); }
            if(AjanlatTermekID != "")
            {
                if(!$.isNumeric(AjanlatTermekID)){FormErros.push("A termék ID nem szám típusú.");}
            }
            if($.trim(AjanlatCim) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a szállítási címet."); }
            if($.trim(AjanlatMennyiseg) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a termék(ek) mennyiségét."); }
            if(FormErros.length == 0 )
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: $('#AjanlatForm').serialize(),
                    url: 'files/uj-ajanlatkeres.php',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //$('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#kerdesButton').hide();
                        $('#AjanlatForm')[0].reset();
                        location.href = "https://my-domain.com/uzenet/uj-ajanlatkeres";
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#AjanlatResult').fadeIn( "slow" ).html('<div class="javascript_rror_div">'+(FormErros.join('<br/>'))+'</div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your button to `type="submit"` and register a `submit` event handler for the form rather than a `click` event handler for the button.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" id="AjanlatForm" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Az Ön neve:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="AjanlatNev" name="AjanlatNev" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >E-mail címe:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="AjanlatEmail" name="AjanlatEmail" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Telefonszáma:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="AjanlatTel" name="AjanlatTel" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Szállítási cím:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input id="AjanlatCim" name="AjanlatCim" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Mennyiség:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AjanlatMennyiseg" name="AjanlatMennyiseg">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="btn selectBtn" id="AjanlatMennyisegTipus" name="AjanlatMennyisegTipus">
              <option  value="Darab">Darab</option>
              <option  value="Kamion">Kamion</option>
              <option  value="Raklap">Raklap</option>
              <option  value="Tekercs">Tekercs</option>
              <option  value="Zsák">Zsák</option>
              <option  value="cm">cm</option>
              <option  value="m">m</option>
              <option  value="m2">m2</option>
              <option  value="m3">m3</option>
            </select>
            </span> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label ajanlat_label" >Üzenet:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <textarea name="AjanlatUzenet" id="AjanlatUzenet" rows="7" class="form-control input-md"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="ajanlat_modal_text">A küldés gombot kérjük csak egyszer nyomja meg.</p>
        <input type="hidden" id="AjanlatTermekID" name="AjanlatTermekID" value="91">
        <button type="submit" id="kerdesButton" class="btn btn-default sidebar_button">Ajánlatkérés elküldése</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div id="AjanlatResult"></div>
      </div>
    </form>



    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        $("#AjanlatKeresBtn").click(function() 

        {

            $('#AjanlatResult').hide();

            $("#AjanlatModal").modal("show");
            $('#AjanlatForm').on('submit', function(e)
            {
                $('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', true);
                e.preventDefault();
                var FormErros = [];
                var AjanlatNev = $('#AjanlatNev').val();
                var AjanlatEmail = $('#AjanlatEmail').val();
                var AjanlatTel = $('#AjanlatTel').val();
                var AjanlatCim = $('#AjanlatCim').val();
                var AjanlatMennyiseg = $('#AjanlatMennyiseg').val();
                var AjanlatUzenet = $('#AjanlatUzenet').val();
                var AjanlatTermekID = $('#AjanlatTermekID').val();
                if($.trim(AjanlatNev) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a nevét."); }
                if($.trim(AjanlatEmail) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg az e-mail címét."); }
                if(AjanlatEmail != "")
                {
                    if(validate_Email(AjanlatEmail) == false){FormErros.push("Elképzelhető, hogy hibásan adta meg az e-mail címét.");}
                }
                if($.trim(AjanlatTel) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a telefonszámát."); }
                if($.trim(AjanlatUzenet) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem írt semmilyen kérdést vagy üzenetet."); }
                if($.trim(AjanlatTermekID) == "") { FormErros.push("Hiányzik a termék ID."); }
                if(AjanlatTermekID != "")
                {
                    if(!$.isNumeric(AjanlatTermekID)){FormErros.push("A termék ID nem szám típusú.");}
                }
                if($.trim(AjanlatCim) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a szállítási címet."); }
                if($.trim(AjanlatMennyiseg) == "") { FormErros.push("Nem adta meg a termék(ek) mennyiségét."); }
                if(FormErros.length == 0 )
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        data: $('#AjanlatForm').serialize(),
                        url: 'files/uj-ajanlatkeres.php',
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            //$('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', false);
                            $('#kerdesButton').hide();
                            $('#AjanlatForm')[0].reset();
                            location.href = "https://my-domain.com/uzenet/uj-ajanlatkeres";
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#AjanlatResult').fadeIn( "slow" ).html('<div class="javascript_rror_div">'+(FormErros.join('<br/>'))+'</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hello!  I only need theese changes? I tried it, its okay. And now that the button is a submit type, i can send the form with the enter button. I pushed the enter 2-3x, and it only submited the form once.

Comment: Hi @Dave599, yeah I think so. Sounds like it's working ok?

Comment: @Dave599 awesome! No problem :)

Comment: Anbd whats the difference between the form submit and the button click? The first one why doest send the form more then once, if i click the button more than once?

Comment: @Dave599 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785241/difference-between-handling-form-submit-or-an-input-type-submit-click-e

Comment: When you disable the button, you are preventing its default behavior. Normally a buttons default behavior in a form is to submit. However, because you changed the type to "button", the button's default behavior is now.. nothing. It is your event handler that is doing the submitting. So disabling the button disables its default behavior but NOT your custom event handler.

Comment: And now that i change the click event to the form submit event, still i need to disable the button?

Comment: Yes, because now your handler is attached to the submit event, which is triggered by the default behavior of the button. If you disable the button the submit event will not fire, and thus your handler will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this to the button:

```
<button class="myButton" type="submit">Click Here</button>
```

And the in the javascript you would need to do this:

```
$(".myButton").click(function(){
    $(".myForm").submit(function(e) {
        // Cancels the form's submit action.
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do post in here
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ajax call with following:

```
        var form = $("form");
        var jqXHR = form.data("jqXHR");
        if (jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.abort();
        }

        form.data("jqXHR", $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#AjanlatForm').serialize(),
            url: 'files/uj-ajanlatkeres.php',
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#kerdesButton').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#kerdesButton').hide();
                $('#AjanlatForm')[0].reset();
                location.href = "https://my-domain.com/uzenet/uj-ajanlatkeres";
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                form.removeData('jqXHR');
            }
        }));
```